# DexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android

i already inserted from the build.app clean and rebuild. i dont know how to fix this problem here's my code.

My inserted code

```
multiDexEnabled true
compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

**Build.app**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.coorsdev.sendsms"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true //attached requires
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}dependencies {
//attached requires
compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

When it runs, this is my result from my Message.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

Comment: Try this **`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`**

Comment: didnt work, same results bro.

Comment: Have you check your dependencies trees with something like `./gradlew app:dependencies`? Check your `libs` directory too.

Comment: sorry . i forgot from libs, i install the 3 types of .jar bcaus i follow for the steps.